# PyCharm weird Unexpected type warning

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm keeps warning me about:

**Unexpected type(s):(int, float)Possible type(s):(SupportsIndex, int)(slice, Iterable[int])**

```
 test = [0] * len(df)
     for i in range(len(df)):
         test[i] = df[i]
         test[i]'<-Here' = test[i]'<-But not here' * (3600 / df2[i])
```

And I don't undestand why it's totally fine on the right side and not on the left.

```
df:
2021-11-19 06:00:00    25
2021-11-19 07:00:00    22
2021-11-19 08:00:00    27
2021-11-19 09:00:00    30
```

Comment: Just disregard the warnings if things are running well. Python is not a typified language, Such type hints were added very recently and they still miss a lot of cases (a lot work in progress). Especially with pandas (which it is complex and it does separate runtime type check (in df). So you see sometime IDE that are confused with types

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Indeed, things are running well. But I'm pedantic when it comes to IDE warnings. Updating PyCharm to newest version (2021.2.3) helped for a while but these warnings seems to come back without any particular reason.

Comment: In any case, do not get me wrong. I think such warnings in IDE are useful, just we need probably few more years until we can get reliable warnings with most common python frameworks/libraries.